# How to add new element to existing 2d string array?

Tags: c#

How to add new element to 2d string array in c#? 
Ex. I have a array

```
string [,] x = new string[,]{{"1","a"},{"2","b"}};
```

Now I want to increase the length array and add "3" and "c" to the top.

Comment: You can't resize a .NET array. Create a new, larger array, or use `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: I'd suggest List<List<String>>

Answer (score 1):

Array's are immutable in terms of length. Once defined, objects cannot be added into them.

You need a expandable collection for that like `List` of your custom class.

```
public class FooBar
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and list like

```
var fooBars = new List<FooBar>
{
    new FooBar() {Foo = "1", Bar = "a"},
    new FooBar() {Foo = "2", Bar = "b"},
};

fooBars.Add(new FooBar() {Foo = "3", Bar = "c"});
```

Also you can now convert the collection to Array like this

```
var myArray = fooBars.ToArray();
```

Comment: as much as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot resize Arrays in C#.
But there are 2 solutions for you:

1. Using `List<T>` `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx`
2. Recreate array everytime after add or remove operations(bad way).

P.S. It looks like you need a `Dictionary<K,V>` for your work(with unic 1st field, called Key).
`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx`

```
var x = new List<List<string>>();
x.Add(new List<string>()
{
    "1", "a"
});
// so on.
```

Comment: @RoJa as much as you wish, like before memory goes off.